# Can't import modules in python even if they are "successfully" installed

Tags: python-2.7, pip, gdal, rasterio

I'm new to this and I've had trouble starting to practice my code because of the libraries and python versions, first I must explain that I had python 3 installed and was trying to install the libraries to process Landsat satellite images with

```
pip install rasterio
pip install gdal
```

**I was never able to install them with repository or packages**, and asking a professor told me that it was because of the version of python and anaconda, and these libraries only work in python 2.7
So I uninstalled the latest version of python and anaconda and replaced them with versions 2.7 of python and anaconda

I downloaded the packages and installed them like this (I also installed pip manually)

```
C:\Users\jenny\Downloads>pip install rasterio-1.0.28-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
C:\Users\jenny\Downloads>pip install GDAL-2.2.4-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

When I try:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio import plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
```

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\NDVILansat.py", line 1, in <module>
    import rasterio
ImportError: No module named rasterio
```

I think my libraries are in this path:

```
import sys; print(sys.path)
```

['C:/Users/jenny/Documents', 'C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib', 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\python27.zip', 'C:\Python27\ DLLs', 'C:\Python27\lib', 'C:\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\ \Python27', 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-36.7.1-py2.7.egg', ' C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg']

> > > ================================= RESTART ============== ==================

But if I try to reinstall the library I get this

`C:\Users\jenny\Downloads>pip install rasterio-1.0.28-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`

Requirement already satisfied: rasterio==1.0.28 from file:///C:/Users/jenny/Downloads/rasterio-1.0.28-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl in c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site- packages (1.0.28)

Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from rasterio==1.0.28) (1.15.1)

Requirement already satisfied: enum34 in c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from rasterio==1.0.28) (1.1.6)

Requirement already satisfied: click-plugins in c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from rasterio==1.0.28) (1.1.1)

Requirement already satisfied: cligj>=0.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from rasterio==1.0.28) (0.7.2)

Requirement already satisfied: attrs in c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from rasterio==1.0.28) (18.2.0)

Requirement already satisfied: gdal~=2.2.4 in c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from rasterio==1.0.28) (2.2.4)`

Requirement already satisfied: snuggs>=1.4.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from rasterio==1.0.28) (1.4.7)

Requirement already satisfied: affine in c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from rasterio==1.0.28) (2.3.1)

Requirement already satisfied: click>=4.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from rasterio==1.0.28) (6.7)

Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.1.6 in c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from snuggs>=1.4.1->rasterio==1.0.28) (2.2.0)

You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 20.3.4 is available.

You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

---

And when I try to open the Anaconda navigator I got this:

```
Browser Error
An unexpected error occurred on Navigator start-up

report
Please report this issue in the anaconda issue tracker

main error
'root_prefix'
Traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\exceptions.py", line 75, in exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 150, in start_app
    window = run_app(splash)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 65, in run_app
    window = MainWindow(splash=splash, tab_project=False)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py", line 168, in __init__
    self.api = AnacondaAPI()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 2294, in AnacondaAPI
    ANACONDA_API = _AnacondaAPI()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 91, in __init__
    self._conda_api = CondaAPI()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\conda_api.py", line 1767, in CondaAPI
    CONDA_API = _CondaAPI()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\conda_api.py", line 350, in __init__
    self.set_conda_prefix(info=get_conda_info())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\conda_api.py", line 505, in set_conda_prefix
    self.ROOT_PREFIX = info['root_prefix']
KeyError: 'root_prefix'
```

In conclusion: I can't use the libraries yet because when I run the code in IDLE it doesn't recognize them despite being installed

At this point I am desperate and I hope it is not a bother to ask about this that becomes easy to solve for some.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might need to use an anaconda command instead of pip, for example:

> conda install -c conda-forge gdal

Also, you could check out:
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html
in case that helps.